# Codeigniter Flash data not getting cleared

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function student_email()
{
    $opt=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $class=$this->input->post('class');
    $edu_level=$this->input->post('edu_level');
    $data=$this->newsletter_model->get_StudentData($opt,$class,$edu_level);
    $subject=$this->input->post('txtSubjectRequired');
    $message=$this->input->post('txtMessageRequired');
    $message=nl2br($message);
    $note="student";//Variable for Identifying Students alone
    //Test Email
    $email=$this->input->post('txtEmail');
    if(trim($email)!=''){
        $note="test";
        $name="User";
        $data=$email;
        $this->sendMail($data,$subject,$message,$note,$name);
    }
    else {
        //$this->sendMail($data,$subject,$message,$note,$text,$name='');
    }
    if($this->session->userdata('mail_status')=="success"){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Mail sent Successfully.');
    }
    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'OOPS.! Mail Sending failed..!.');
    }
    $this->session->unset_userdata('mail_status');
    redirect('/newsletter/student/'.$opt , 'refresh');
    /**Note:
     * Filter by field of study and Last topic need to be coded..
     */
}
```

- When click the back button, `flash data` not getting cleared.
- is it a cache problem..? any other
- any solution instead of disabling cache? 
  Please help me with the solution..

Comment: As per CodeIgniter "CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared." [Session Class][https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html] Once u used the flashdata, it will be be cleared automatically, `$this->session->unset_userdata` is not related here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. actually my doubt is when click the back button why should it again displays?

Comment: If you can share your view and application logic (when back button is fired and which view it shows then), it will be easy to debug. Here can't see any `$this->session->flashdata('success');` which print the success message.

Comment: when  $this->sendMail($data,$subject,$message,$note,$name);  invokes $this->load->view('newsletter/student'); will be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
?>
```

- I found this code

  It solves the problem..